# Can I extract libtool configuration from automake/autoconf for seperate use?

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake, libtool

I have a simple C++ library which uses a short autoconf, automake and libtool to build a shared library object.

Now I want to be able to dynamically compile new code at run-time in my program, by:

- Output code to a temporary file (say /tmp/code.cc)
- Compile to a library
- Dynamically load code.so into my code

I want to find the commands I need to run to do this. I can see the commands used by running 'make -n', but I really don't want to try using awk to search and replace bits of these commands!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be decomposed into following sub-problems:

- Determine how you have compiled the program itself (compiler and / or flags should not be mixed, especially not in case of the C++ language).
  You do this by exporting `CC`, `CXX`, `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` to the `config.h` file using [AC_DEFINE](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Symbols.html) `autoconf` macro in `configure.ac`. Or you may use `AC_SUBST` and your custom `header.h.in` to store those variables in a file of your choice.
- Then you call compiler `CC` giving him `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` or `CXX` with `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. However, if you want to load those files by your program, you may consider using the Libtool library called [libltdl](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html#Using-libltdl), which implements plug-in stuff in a cross-platform way.
- You may consider using `libtool` script as a cross-platform compilation wrapper, but you will have to [study](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Compile-mode.html#Compile-mode) it a bit since it is somehow arcane - there are compilation, linking and "installation" phases, but they are handled in a cross-platform way and if you pass the `-sharee` argument, some additional flags you need (`-fPIC` and possibly others) will be passed automagically.

Comment: Your reply has convinced me that this problem is hard enough I'm going to tackle the problem in a different way -- but I believe your answer is correct if anyone else is ever brave enough to do so!